# How can I do INSERT with SQLITE with ON CONFLICT REPLACE strategy?

Tags: sqlite, prisma

I'm experimenting with Prisma, and I'm liking it so far. The only thing I can't figure out is how to specify a `on conflict` strategy.

I'm using Sqlite, but I can't find any documentation for Prisma to allow me to insert data with a more resilient strategy against duplicates.

How can apply IGNORE/REPLACE/etc. from the [ON CONFLICT DOC](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Prisma doesn't have built-in support for `ON CONFLICT`. The [`upsert`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#upsert) method might help here, otherwise, you can use [`$queryRaw`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw).